# Custom event tracking doesn't send event

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get custom event tracking to work on my website.

**My problem is: The custom GA tracking is not being send. I cannot see it in GA or in my network tab. Also there is no error in the developer console.**

How can I debug / fix the problem?

**What I have tried to solve the problem:**

We use GTM to implement GA. GA works fine.

I have created a function to get triggered when a event occurs. I have tested the function - it fires properly when the event is being triggered.

The the ga 'send' command uses functions to dynamically generate the right tracking. I have tested the functions individually inside a console.log >> they work fine.

I have tested that the 'ga' command is available. It is not being rejected by the console with an error message like 'unknown'. So the command is available. It just doesn't work properly >> no error message at all.

**Technical Background:**

We use WordPress 5.0.2 to run our website.

I have tested it locally (WAMP) and on our staging environment.

**The function:**

```
function stepTracking() {
  ga('send', 'event', eventLabel(), eventAction, eventCategory());
}
```

My goal is to A. Understand why the command is not working and B. Send the tracking properly.

Thank you guys,
Max

Comment: is eventLabel(), eventCategory() returning a string? and is eventAction also set?

Comment: @funkysoul yes, the functions and the variable are returning strings

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a GA event as opposed to a GTM event. Try the [dataLayer.push mechanism](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events).